# HTML JQuery or PHP, Writing data to a textfile

Tags: php, jquery, html, fwrite, closest

I have the following code that takes the closest sibling element of a button with the class "description" and prints its contents out to the console. I would like to take this content and write it to a specific location in a textfile. My code is follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr><td>Name</td><td>Jenkins</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Job</td><td>Accountant</td></tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td class="description">
                He's just a man.
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="learn">Learn</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".learn").click(function(){
        var data = $(this).closest("td").siblings(".description").text();
        console.log(data);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The file that I'm looking to write to is like this:

```
Var data = [
  {
    name: group1,
    items: [
      {
        name: "bob",
        job: "salesman",
        description: "underground comedian"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: group2,
    items: [
      {
        name: "susan",
        job: "chef",
        description: "loves McDonalds"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So I would like to be able to create a new element of this textfile wherever specified (group1 or group2) and insert the information that is grabbed by the script.

I've been reading that using JS and JQuery for this kind of work that I want done is not a great idea, so if anyone could explain how I could accomplish this kind of work with PHP or a combination of both that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change your JS code to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".learn").click(function(){
    var data = $(this).closest("td").siblings(".description").text();
    $.post('save.php', 'data=' + data); //AJAX call to save.php
    });
</script>
```

Then create a save.php file and put this in it:

```
<?php
file_put_contents('textfile.txt', $_POST['data']);
```

I am not sure how you want to format this inside this textfile but this should get you started.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'd like to format it where 'text.txt' would have a structure similar to the "data" file I included above. Where I would create another element with name: "Jenkins", job: "Accountant", description: "He's just a man" in either group1 or group2

Comment: also, for some reason when the description is written to textfile.txt there is an indentation and about 4 tabs before the content starts. Any idea why that is?